# What are conditions necessary to calculate a confidence interval for population mean?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

if we have $1250$ values(sample), are we then able to calculate $99$% confidence interval less than  $0.1$ ? how do i check if its possible ?

my first thought was to try going backwards in the process of finding confidence interval. which is impossible as many parameters are missing

i am a bit confused here so any hints are appreciated !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Confidence interval for what? Population mean? It doesn't say. If we assume the distribution is "nice," there is still the issue of the population variance. Without some knowledge about it, we cannot know whether a $99\%$ confidence interval of specified width can be produced.

Comment: assuming its mean for legal concrete limit $kg/in^2$

Comment: I have changed the title of your question. I hope it is a better match for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is how to check whether this is possible.

My guess is that you are supposed to assume that the
sample mean $\bar X$ is very nearly normal because of
the large sample size $n = 1250.$ And then to assume
that an approximate $99\%$ confidence interval is given
by $\bar X \pm 2.58 S/\sqrt{n}$, where $S$ is the sample
standard deviation. Thus the length of the CI would be about
$5.16 S/\sqrt{1250},$ which you could compare with the
desired length of the CI (which I take to be) $0.1.$

However, even in applied situations, it is possible to
encounter samples from distributions for which the 
assumptions of the previous paragraph are not valid.
In particular, as remarked by @AndreNicholas, the parent population must have a finite standard deviation.
Otherwise a CI based on a sample standard deviation $S$ cannot
be the basis for a large-sample confidence interval.

If the original data pass a test for normality, then
the assumptions are likely OK. Less rigorously, if a histogram
of the data seems roughly symmetrical and has no far
outliers, then the assumptions may be OK.

The figure below shows histograms of two samples of size $n=1250$. The first (at left)
is from a normal populaion, has $\bar X = 99.8,$ $S_X = 14.4$ and
a 99% CI $(98.76, 100.86)$ for $\mu$, which is valid (even if somewhat
longer than you have in mind). The second shows a sample from
a badly-behaved distribution for which the CI formula above is
not valid.

[image]

Comment: i may should add that somehow this question is the second part of a question where i had to find 95% CI for a sample of 20 values. Btw how do you get $5.16 S/\sqrt{1250},$ ? shouldnt it be $2.58 S/\sqrt{1250}$?

Comment: Yes of course, the value of $n$ would make a difference in the length of the CI. The quantity $2.58 S\sqrt{n}$ is called the _margin of error_. The _length_ of the CI is double that.

Comment: ah alright. But how do i compare $5.16 S/\sqrt{1250}$ with $0.1$ as i dont  have $s$(standard deviation)? is there a way to find it ? maybe somehow use the standard deviation i found in the part 1 of the question ?

Comment: nope, i dont know the population mean , i only have sample mean...

Comment: how would i solve the question if i have the population mean ?

Comment: CI for pop mean requires pop SD or an estimate of it. Did 'part 1' involve finding some info about SD? Now it is becoming less clear to me whether the 1250 values are really a 'sample' or they are supposed to be taken as the population. Seems either this is a horribly screwed up problem or there is background info not mentioned here.

Comment: par1: a survey that studys the legal limit results in 20 values (the values are given in the description). i had to calculate the average limit with 95% CI. i solved that.

Part2: are you able to calculate 99% CI less than 0.1, if are allowed to perform max 1250 measurements?